# How can I really disable the Cmd to Win key mapping in Parallels Desktop 5?

Tags: keyboard, mapping, parallels-desktop

Removed it from `System Preferences > Keyboard`. No go.
Remapped <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. No go.
Ripping out the <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> key shouldn't be the solution. Anyone?...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works for me, but I have it remapped like this:

[image: Parallels Keys]

So cmd is really control for Windows.

Answer (score 7):

I found that mapping a different key to the <kbd>Win</kbd> command did not remove the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key being mapped to <kbd>Win</kbd>.  What worked for me was to map <kbd>Cmd</kbd> to <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

[image: Cmd key mapped to Win key]

All the other shortcuts such as <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (save), <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (copy), etc still worked but hitting <kbd>Cmd</kbd> by itself now just activates the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key which really does nothing by itself.

Comment: I can verify that this is a valid solution for Parallels 10 with Windows 8.1.

Comment: This works but has the unfortunate consequence of disabling ⌘+C for copy etc on my machine (Yosemite, Parallels 10, Windows 8). Instead I mapped ⌘ to Ctrl.

Comment: @philwilks Check that you still have ⌘+C mapped in the window shown above.

Comment: Agreed, this solution is great, but mapping to `Control` might be better.  The Copy/Paste shortcuts are set separately anyway so it doesn't appear to mess anything up either way.  So glad the Dumb Start menu doesn't appear any more when I show my desktop!  Works on Parallels Desktop 10.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Parallels Desktop preferences and disable key mapping for key which behaves abnormally ("Cmd > win" in our case) as shown on the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: I already disabled it and it doesn't have any effect. Does it work for you?
BTW, I'm running 5.0.9370.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Krumstick](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/) to remap the windows key inside Windows.

Comment: Thanks. Will probably do that if I don't find anything on the Mac side...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you. But the main problem for me was the `CMD + arrow` keys I use all the time to go to the start or end of a line.

This can be remapped without problems, this way you can use all your normal shortcuts from MacOS too. The second I get a Mac keyboard muscle memory kicks in and this is a good compromise :)

[image]